# Separate subject line from Subject Prefix

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm just wondering if it's possible to only include %%emailname_%% as the prefix when sending test emails, but somehow keep the actual subject line within the email?

Basically, I'm looking to solve the issue of Litmus populating the email name as the subject line when sending in new emails/proofs